# Android: Status Bar Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

Is there any way to catch/detect the start or instance of the system notifications on the status bar? I am planning to redirect the notifications appearing on the status bar into a simple toast or the likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't any way of doing that.

EDIT : Adding example to handle the sdcard events

```
IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT);
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL);
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED);
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED);
f.addDataScheme("file");
registerReceiver(mScanListener, f);
```

private BroadcastReceiver mScanListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
  }
}

Comment: How about for specific notifications? Let say mounting and unmounting of SD card? I would like to create a simple toast when a SD card had been mounted/unmounted from the device.

Comment: For the SD card related notifications, you can listen for ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED/UNMOUNTED notifications.

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure that out. Is it right to use a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: I've added the example in my answer.

Comment: I see. I guess my first instinct is correct. :) Thanks so much for your help!